# Arc length paramatrizations satisfy original system of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, parametric, systems-of-equations

Say we have a system of differential equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x'''(t)+f(t)x'(t)=0\\
y'''(t)+f(t)y'(t)=0
\end{cases}
$$
on an interval $[a,b]$, along with the restriction that
$$
x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2=1
$$
on $[a,b]$.

Now, Euler proved that as long as $x(t),y(t)$ are continuous and not both zero at a point, then we can re-parametrize $x,y$ to some functions $\tilde x,\tilde y$ which have the same image as $x,y$ but are arc-length parametrized.

Now, say we have a solution $\big(x^*(t),y^*(t)\big)$ to
$$
\begin{cases}
x'''(t)+f(t)x'(t)=0\\
y'''(t)+f(t)y'(t)=0
\end{cases}
$$
that satisfies the hypotheses needed to apply the previously mentioned re-parametrization.  Say $\big(\tilde x^*(t), \tilde y^*(t)\big)$ are this re-parametrization, so they have the same image of $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$ on $[a,b]$ and satisfy
$$
x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2=1.
$$

Is it still the case that
$$
\begin{cases}
(\tilde x^*)'''(t)+f(t)(\tilde x^*)'(t)=0\\
(\tilde y^*)'''(t)+f(t)(\tilde y^*)'(t)=0?
\end{cases}
$$

Note: I'm not necessarily looking for a proof of this, just some intuition.

Comment: There is no reason for that. Your re-parametrization has the form $(x^*(t), y^*(t))=(x(\phi(t)), y(\phi(t))$, for some "change of variable function" $\phi$. Look at what happens to your system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the view of zyx and Etienne. In the general case, i.e. for any function $f(t)$, the solutions of that system cannot be reparametrized to have 
$(x′)^2+(y′)^2=1$. Nevertheless, it is of interest to see if some particular functions $f(t)$ allow to reparametrize the solutions according to the condition $(x′)^2+(y′)^2=1$

There was a big mistake in my first answer. I am very sorry for that. The previous attachment is now remplaced by the corrected one below. In fact, the solution is much simpler than before.

In this particular case of $c_1-c_2=n\pi$, all the solutions are circles, which could have been guessed immediately.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Can we push this any further to solve our differential equations?

Comment: "our differential equations" : What exactly do you mean ?

Comment: The original wording of the problem includes three ODEs and it has been solved : $f(t), x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are formally expressed. Now, if the wording of the problem do NOT includes the third ODE, then the function $f(t)$ must be explicitly expressed if we want to go further.

Comment: Understood. By the way, what did you use to type this up? It's not LaTeX. What is it and why do you use it over LaTeX?

Comment: @ Logan Tartham : I use LateX if the typing is not too complicated. But if the typography requires too much skill or if I have not enough time, I use MathType and other software for drawings.

Comment: Wait, we can have $f(t)\neq1$ and still find solutions which satisfy $x'''(t)+f(t)x'(t)=0=y'''(t)+f(t)y'(t)$ and $x'^2+y'^2=1$.  For example, if $f(t)=4$, then the curves $x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\cos{2t},y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2t}$ are solutions.  I didn't see an error in your analysis anywhere, though.  Am I missing something or is there a problem?

Comment: You are right : there was a obvious missprint in the last formula $f(t)$ which is now corrected. The example $x(t)=(1/2)cos2t, y(t)=(1/2)sin(2t)$ belongs to the set of solutions, in the particular case of $c_0=2 , c_1=pi , c_2=0, x_0=y_0=0$

Comment: Your help has been invaluable.  I'm a little new to Stack Exchange; is there a way I can award you additional bounty?

Comment: Don't mention it. Thank you for the compliment. By the way, there was still a detail missing in the previous attached document. I will add it soon.

Comment: my research partner and I are working on a research project and this is a nontrivial part of it.  I feel we need to give some credit to you.  My email is in my bio, let me know if you want credit and how to credit you.

Comment: When I work as a consultant on a contactual basis, of course I am paid for the job. When I answer to a question on a forum, this is just friendly advice on my part. So, I don't want any credit. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of that system cannot be reparametrized to have $(x')^2 + (y')^2$ constant for nonconstant $f(t)$.  Reparametrization alters the velocity vector but here $x',y'$ are the "spatial" coordinates and $x'',y''$ the velocities.  For variable positive $f(t)$ the solution curves cut across the solutions with $f=c$ for different $c$, and all of the latter are circles (for $c > 0$).

If you did reparametrize to have ${x''}^2 + {y''}^2$ constant, there would be no reason for it to satisfy the same system of differential equations, but $(x'(t),y'(t))$ would follow the same curves.